# Smart Tic Tac Toe, a reinforcement learning approach

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, pyqt

I'm currently familiarizing myself with reinforcement learning (RL). For convenience, instead of manually entering coordinates in the terminal, I created a very simple UI for testing trained agents and play games against them. You can experiment and play around with it using different hyperparameters but as this is a very basic reinforcement learning algorithm I did not get good results for boards larger than the standard tic tac toe size (3 x 3).

For using it just run `python3 ui.py` the agent will be trained and then the UI will be loaded and you can play against the trained agent.

How to improve efficiency / memory requirements, they are negligible but an improvement does not hurt since memory scores are stored for updates. Can I to improve agent accuracy / ability to, win games / prevent human from winning specially on larger boards? And of course general feedback is appreciated. And as I'm currently learning RL concepts, I'm aware that there is a lot more to learn and sooner or later I might find answers to the RL technical questions I have however I'm always open for feedback.

Here's what the UI looks like:

[image]

`helper.py`

```
import numpy as np


class TicBase:
    """
    Base class with useful utils/helpers.
    """

    def __init__(self, board_size=3, empty_value=0, x_value=2, o_value=3):
        """
        Initialize common settings.
        Args:
            board_size: int, board cell x cell size.
            empty_value: int, representation of available cells.
            x_value: int, representation(internal not for display) of X on the board.
            o_value: int, representation(internal not for display) of O on the board.
        """
        self.board_size = board_size
        self.board = np.ones((board_size, board_size)) * empty_value
        self.empty_value = empty_value
        self.x_value = x_value
        self.o_value = o_value

    def get_empty_cells(self, board=None):
        """
        Get empty locations that are available.
        Args:
            board: numpy array of shape n, n where n: self.board_size.

        Returns:
            A list of (x, y) empty indices of the board.
        """
        board = board if board is not None else self.board
        empty_locations = np.where(board == self.empty_value)
        return list(zip(*empty_locations))

    def check_game_ended(self, board):
        """
        Check for empty cells.
        Args:
            board: numpy array of shape n, n where n: self.board_size.

        Returns:
            True if there are empty cells, False otherwise.
        """
        return not np.any(board == self.empty_value)

    def check_win(self, symbol, board=None):
        """
        Check if there is a winner.
        Args:
            symbol: int, representation of the player on the board.
            board: numpy array of shape n, n where n: self.board_size.

        Returns:
            symbol if symbol is winner else None.
        """
        board = board if board is not None else self.board
        result = (
            np.all(board == symbol, axis=0).any()
            or np.all(board == symbol, axis=1).any()
            or np.all(board.diagonal() == symbol)
            or np.all(board[::-1].diagonal() == symbol)
        )
        if result:
            return symbol

    def reset_game(self, symbol=None):
        """
        Reset board.
        Args:
            symbol: int, representation of the winning player on the board.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        self.board = (
            np.ones((self.board_size, self.board_size)) * self.empty_value
        )
```

`agent.py`

```
from helper import TicBase
import numpy as np


class TicAgent(TicBase):
    """
    Tic Tac Toe agent.
    """

    def __init__(
        self, agent_settings, board_size=3, empty_value=0, x_value=2, o_value=3
    ):
        """
        Initialize agent settings.
        Args:
            agent_settings: Dictionary that has the following keys:
                - 'epsilon': float, value from 0 to 1 representing degree
                    of random(exploratory) moves.
                - 'learning_rate': float, Learning rate used to update values.
                - 'symbol': int, representation of the agent on the board.
            board_size: int, board cell x cell size.
            empty_value: int, representation of available cells.
            x_value: int, representation(internal not for display) of X on the board.
            o_value: int, representation(internal not for display) of O on the board.
        """
        TicBase.__init__(self, board_size, empty_value, x_value, o_value)
        self.symbol = agent_settings['symbol']
        self.opponent_symbol = x_value if self.symbol == o_value else o_value
        self.learning_rate = agent_settings['learning_rate']
        self.epsilon = agent_settings['epsilon']
        self.game_scores = {}

    @staticmethod
    def get_game_id(board):
        """
        Convert game to string representation for storing game scores.
        Args:
            board: numpy array of shape n, n where n: self.board_size.

        Returns:
            string representation of the game.
        """
        return ''.join(board.reshape(-1).astype(int).astype(str))

    def calculate_score(self, board):
        """
        Calculate game score which depends on the winner/loser.
        Args:
            board: numpy array of shape n, n where n: self.board_size.

        Returns:
            score.
        """
        game_id = self.get_game_id(board)
        score = self.game_scores.get(game_id)
        if score is not None:
            return score
        score = 0
        winner = self.check_win(self.symbol, board) or (
            self.check_win(self.opponent_symbol, board)
        )
        if winner == self.symbol:
            score = 1
        if not winner and not self.check_game_ended(board):
            score = 0.5
        self.game_scores[game_id] = score
        return score

    def generate_move(self, board, empty_locations, learning=True):
        """
        Generate a random/best value move according to self.epsilon.
        Args:
            board: numpy array of shape n, n where n: self.board_size which
                represents the game most-recent state.
            empty_locations: A list of (x, y) empty indices of the board.
            learning: If True, exploration is allowed.

        Returns:
            Chosen empty_locations index.
        """
        probability = np.random.rand()
        if probability < self.epsilon and learning:
            return np.random.choice(len(empty_locations))
        possible_moves = [board.copy() for _ in empty_locations]
        for idx, empty_location in enumerate(empty_locations):
            r, c = empty_location
            possible_moves[idx][r, c] = self.symbol
        scores = [
            self.calculate_score(possible) for possible in possible_moves
        ]
        return np.argmax(scores)

    def step(self, board):
        """
        Take turn.
        Args:
            board: numpy array of shape n, n where n: self.board_size which
                represents the game most-recent state.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        empty_locations = self.get_empty_cells(board)
        move_idx = self.generate_move(board, empty_locations)
        r, c = empty_locations[move_idx]
        board[r, c] = self.symbol

    def update_game_scores(self, game_history, winner):
        """
        Update agent weights.
        Args:
            game_history: A list of numpy arrays(game boards) of 1 full game.
            winner: int representation of agent/opponent.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        target = 1 if winner == self.symbol else 0
        for game in reversed(game_history):
            game_id = self.get_game_id(game)
            old_score = self.calculate_score(game)
            updated_score = old_score + self.learning_rate * (
                target - old_score
            )
            self.game_scores[game_id] = updated_score
            target = updated_score
```

`trainer.py`

```
from helper import TicBase
from agent import TicAgent


class TicTrainer(TicBase):
    """
    Tool for agent training.
    """

    def __init__(
        self, agent_settings, board_size=3, empty_value=0, x_value=2, o_value=3
    ):
        """
        Initialize agents for training.
        Args:
            agent_settings: A list of 2 dictionaries for 2 agents.
            board_size: int, board cell x cell size.
            empty_value: int, representation of available cells.
            x_value: int, representation(internal not for display) of X on the board.
            o_value: int, representation(internal not for display) of O on the board.
        """
        TicBase.__init__(self, board_size, empty_value, x_value, o_value)
        self.agent_1 = TicAgent(
            agent_settings[0], board_size, empty_value, x_value, o_value
        )
        self.agent_2 = TicAgent(
            agent_settings[1], board_size, empty_value, x_value, o_value
        )

    def play_one(self, game_history):
        """
        Play one game.
        Args:
            game_history: A list of numpy arrays(game boards) of 1 full game.

        Returns:
            symbol or 'end' or None.
        """
        board = self.board
        for agent in [self.agent_1, self.agent_2]:
            agent.step(board)
            game_history.append(board.copy())
            if self.check_win(agent.symbol, board):
                return agent.symbol
            if self.check_game_ended(board):
                return 'end'

    def train_step(self):
        """
        1 training step/iteration and update.
        Returns:
            None
        """
        game_history = []
        while True:
            winner = self.play_one(game_history)
            if winner in ['end', self.x_value, self.o_value]:
                break
        self.agent_1.update_game_scores(game_history, winner)
        self.agent_2.update_game_scores(game_history, winner)
        self.reset_game(winner)

    def train_basic(self, iterations):
        """
        Train using the most basic value function.
        Args:
            iterations: Training loop size.

        Returns:
            self.agent_1, self.agent2
        """
        for i in range(iterations):
            percent = round((i + 1) / iterations * 100, 2)
            print(
                f'\r Training agent ... iteration: '
                f'{i}/{iterations} - {percent}% completed',
                end='',
            )
            self.train_step()
        return self.agent_1, self.agent_2
```

`ui.py`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QDesktopWidget,
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLabel,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import numpy as np
import sys
from helper import TicBase
from trainer import TicTrainer


class TicCell(QPushButton):
    """
    Tic Tac Toe cell.
    """

    def __init__(self, location):
        """
        Initialize cell location.
        Args:
            location: Tuple, (row, col).
        """
        super(QPushButton, self).__init__()
        self.location = location


class TicUI(QMainWindow, TicBase):
    """
    Tic Tac Toe interface.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        window_title='Smart Tic Tac Toe',
        board_size=3,
        empty_value=0,
        x_value=2,
        o_value=3,
        agent=None,
    ):
        """
        Initialize game settings.
        Args:
            window_title: Display window name.
            board_size: int, the board will be of size(board_size, board_size).
            empty_value: int representation of an empty cell.
            x_value: int representation of a cell containing X.
            o_value: int representation of a cell containing O.
            agent: Trained TicAgent object.
        """
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        TicBase.__init__(
            self,
            board_size=board_size,
            empty_value=empty_value,
            x_value=x_value,
            o_value=o_value,
        )
        self.setWindowTitle(window_title)
        self.agent = agent
        if self.agent is not None:
            self.agent.board = self.board
        self.text_map = {
            x_value: 'X',
            o_value: 'O',
            empty_value: '',
            'X': x_value,
            'O': o_value,
            '': empty_value,
        }
        win_rectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        center_point = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        win_rectangle.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.score_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.human_score = 0
        self.agent_score = 0
        self.score_board = QLabel()
        self.update_score_board()
        self.setStyleSheet('QPushButton:!hover {color: yellow}')
        self.cells = [
            [TicCell((c, r)) for r in range(board_size)]
            for c in range(board_size)
        ]
        self.cell_layouts = [QHBoxLayout() for _ in self.cells]
        self.adjust_layouts()
        self.adjust_cells()
        self.update_cell_values()
        self.show()

    def adjust_layouts(self):
        """
        Adjust score board and cell layouts.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.score_layout)
        for cell_layout in self.cell_layouts:
            self.main_layout.addLayout(cell_layout)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def adjust_cells(self):
        """
        Adjust display cells.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        self.score_layout.addWidget(self.score_board)
        self.score_board.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        for row_index, row in enumerate(self.cells):
            for cell in row:
                cell.setFixedSize(50, 50)
                cell.clicked.connect(self.game_step)
                self.cell_layouts[row_index].addWidget(cell)

    def get_empty_cells(self, board=None):
        """
        Get empty cell locations.

        Returns:
            A list of indices that represent currently empty cells.
        """
        empty_locations = super().get_empty_cells()
        for empty_location in empty_locations:
            r, c = empty_location
            cell_text = self.cells[r][c].text()
            assert cell_text == self.text_map[self.empty_value], (
                f'location {empty_location} has a cell value of {cell_text}'
                f'and board value of {self.board[r][c]}'
            )
        return empty_locations

    def update_score_board(self):
        """
        Update the display scores.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        self.score_board.setText(
            f'Human {self.human_score} - ' f'{self.agent_score} Agent'
        )

    def reset_cell_colors(self):
        """
        Reset display cell text colors.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        for row_idx in range(self.board_size):
            for col_idx in range(self.board_size):
                self.cells[row_idx][col_idx].setStyleSheet('color: yellow')

    def reset_game(self, symbol=None):
        """
        Reset board and display cells and update display scores.
        Args:
            symbol: int, self.x_value or self.o_value.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        super().reset_game(symbol)
        self.update_cell_values()
        if symbol == self.x_value:
            self.human_score += 1
        if symbol == self.o_value:
            self.agent_score += 1
        self.update_score_board()
        self.reset_cell_colors()

    def modify_step(self, cell_location, value):
        """
        Modify board and display cells.
        Args:
            cell_location: tuple, representing indices(row, col).
            value: int, self.x_value or self.o_value.

        Returns:
            True if the clicked cell is not empty, None otherwise.
        """
        r, c = cell_location
        board_value = self.board[r, c]
        cell_value = self.cells[r][c].text()
        if not board_value == self.empty_value:
            return True
        assert cell_value == self.text_map[self.empty_value], (
            f'mismatch between board value({board_value}) '
            f'and cell value({cell_value}) for location {(r, c)}'
        )
        if value == self.x_value:
            self.cells[r][c].setStyleSheet('color: red')
        self.board[r, c] = value
        self.cells[r][c].setText(f'{self.text_map[value]}')

    def game_step(self):
        """
        Post cell-click step(human step and agent step)

        Returns:
            None
        """
        cell = self.sender()
        stop = self.modify_step(cell.location, self.x_value)
        if stop:
            return
        x_win = self.check_win(self.x_value)
        if x_win is not None:
            self.reset_game(self.x_value)
            return
        empty_locations = self.get_empty_cells()
        if not empty_locations:
            self.reset_game()
            return
        choice = np.random.choice(len(empty_locations))
        if self.agent:
            choice = self.agent.generate_move(
                self.board, empty_locations, False
            )
        self.modify_step(empty_locations[choice], self.o_value)
        o_win = self.check_win(self.o_value)
        if o_win is not None:
            self.reset_game(self.o_value)

    def update_cell_values(self):
        """
        Sync display cells with self.board

        Returns:
            None
        """
        for row_index, row in enumerate(self.board):
            for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
                update_value = self.text_map[self.board[row_index][col_index]]
                self.cells[row_index][col_index].setText(f'{update_value}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = [
        {'symbol': 2, 'epsilon': 0.1, 'learning_rate': 0.5},
        {'symbol': 3, 'epsilon': 0.1, 'learning_rate': 0.5},
    ]
    train = TicTrainer(s)
    a1, a2 = train.train_basic(10000)
    test = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TicUI(agent=a2)
    sys.exit(test.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

### Cell value representation

It's good that you've distinguished this:

> representation(internal not for display)

however, I'm not clear on the reason for making these integers configurable. You're probably better off making an `Enum`:

```
class TicValue(Enum):
    EMPTY = 0
    X = 2
    O = 3
```

This can still be compatible with Numpy, because `.value` will return those integers.

### Truthy coalesce

```
board = board if board is not None else self.board
```

has shorthand:

```
board = board or self.board
```

as long as `board` doesn't have any funny business overriding `__bool__` or `__len__`.

### Boolean equivalent cast

```
target = 1 if winner == self.symbol else 0
```

can be

```
target = int(winner == self.symbol)
```

### Unpacking

```
    self.agent_1 = TicAgent(
        agent_settings[0], board_size, empty_value, x_value, o_value
    )
    self.agent_2 = TicAgent(
        agent_settings[1], board_size, empty_value, x_value, o_value
    )
```

can be

```
self.agent_1, self.agent_2 = (
    TicAgent(settings, board_size, empty_value, x_value, o_value)
    for settings in agent_settings
)
```

### In-band signalling

```
    Returns:
        symbol or 'end' or None.
```

is not very convenient for other functions to process. Consider splitting this apart into

```
def play_one(self, game_history: List[ndarray]) -> (
    bool,            # is end
    Optional[str],   # symbol or None
):
    # ...
    return False, agent.symbol
    # ...
    return True, None
```

### Display map

```
    self.text_map = {
        x_value: 'X',
        o_value: 'O',
        empty_value: '',
        'X': x_value,
        'O': o_value,
        '': empty_value,
    }
```

is a little surprising. You're using this as a map in both directions. It would be safer, and a better guarantee of correctness, for this to be split into forward- and back-maps.

Comment: Ah, so my warning about overriding `__len__` turns out to be applicable. Adding type hints to your function signatures and member variables will make it clear which variables can receive this kind of treatment.